# Add items to portfolio page via dashboard

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In one theme (FloZo) I've seen a nice functionality and I would like to learn how to make something similar. It's about a portfolio page, take a look at the [demo](http://www.flyerzone.co.uk/freewptheme/) "Our Work section".

1. You create a page and give it a template (Work archive) via Pages menu - more or less understood
2. You don't add any pictures there!
3. In your Dashboard you have a nice "work" section, where you can choose "make a new work item" - you add pictures with titles and descriptions there. - This is the big trick!

Now: my newbie idea on how it works:

1. The template is just the "body" of the page with the title
2. The dashboard "work" section must be doing something like this:

When you post a work item, it pastes/appends the whole item code into your page (like an item template code) with your specific image and text. It also creates an item-specific page (it's where you end up after clicking on an item).

My question is: is there any slightest possibility to add such a functionality to a Wordpress theme?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I see it:

The page template, 'Work Archive' has the loop that is displaying posts of 'Work' post type.

So to achieve this first you have to add the [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) of your liking, and then in the page template add a custom loop to display these:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
       'posts_per_page' => -1 //or whatever you choose
    );
    $work_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($work_query->have_posts()) : while ($work_query->have_posts()) : $work_query -> the_post(); ?>
      <!-- loop content goes here -->
    <?php 
    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata(); // always reset post data after custom loops
?>
```

If you need more info pleae don't hesitate to ask.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for your answer Bojana! I read your post a couple of times and I think it's the right direction, but I do have a couple of questions: 1) What does the "-1" stand for? 2) is the loop already in the code, or should I add it instead of the comment? If it's not there yet, how should it look more or less? 3) If I add my custom post type, will it display in the Dashboard?

Comment: I would say that you are jumping ahead with functionalities like these if you are just starting with wordpress. Go over some tutorials first, there are a lot of them out there. To answer your questions: -1 means to display all of the posts, 2. no, you ll have to add it to the page template file, 3. yes, if you set it, read over the link i sent

Comment: Ok, you're right, I'll rather start with something simple :) Big thnx anyway!